# Что делать если у меня постоянно создаётся в базе данных одни и те же данные которые я вписал?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite3

как мне убрать постоянное создание данных в бд.

```
def add_user(self, id, name, survived, infected, paid_days):
        with self.connection:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `stats` (user_id, user_name, survived, infected, paid_days) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (id, name, survived, infected, paid_days))
            self.connection.commit()
```

И как проверить есть ли эти данные которые я вписал в бд?
тоесть через try: или через if..

Comment: Когда создаете таблицу сделать поле `user_id`  типа `UNIQUE`, при попытке вставить данные уже имеющиеся в таблице ловить ошибку через `try` - `except`

Comment: Спасибо помогло.